# Q. Importing data from Excel as Cell Array

Tags: matlab

How do I import data as cell arrays?

I have an excel file that has data in 2*200 table. It looks something like this:

```
0 1 2 ...
0 0 0 ...
```

I would like to import this data in Matlab (manually for now, eventually I'll learn how to do it with script) in a 1*200 cell array, with each cell containing the column of data. Something like this:

```
[0,0] [1,0] [2,0] ...
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use columnB = xlsread(filename,'B:B') to read the whole column, but this approach isn't very efficient.

you should first read the data from the relevant range in the xls file,

than read each column into a cell in a cell array

Comment: How do you read each column into a cell? So I can read the first row and create a cell array of the size I want, but then how do I shove each column into the individual cells?

Comment: try mat2cell
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html